# Debugging application gives me a red line

Tags: android, eclipse, sign

On Manifest, I get an error for Debugging

```
<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:debuggable="false">
```

I am trying click for apk in Android tools >> Export signed Application Package" but I don't know how I got an error.
The Lint Warning for it "Avoid hardcoding the debug mode; leaving it out allows debug and release builds to automatically assign one"

Can anyone help?

Comment: please paste your error fully here

Comment: I removed `android:debuggable="false"` attribute from the manifest, and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you Create the Signed .APK / (release .APK) means, you must remove the `android:debuggable="false"` it is only for debugging purpose not for release.

change this

```
<application
  android:allowBackup="true"
  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:debuggable="false">
```

Into like this

```
<application
 android:allowBackup="true"
 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
 android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
android:debuggable="false"
```

The error is telling you not to hard code it (omit it) and it will assign the value itself depending on what you are doing. If you tell AS to debug, it will set it to debug. If you export your apk it will set it to false.

Comment: No problem. Make sure you mark someone's answer as accepted so the question is removed from the active list